# remove start codon from final println

Tags: java

I need to print out everything between a start codon atg and one of three end codons tga, taa, and tag. I have been trying to solve this problem for a couple days now but I can't seem to find a way to remove the start codon from what gets printed out at the end EX: If you use my code it will print out ATGAAA but I need it to print out only AAA.

```
public class GeneFinderYang {



        public static int findStopIndex(String dna, int index){
            int stop1 = dna.indexOf("tga", index);
            if (stop1 == -1 || (stop1 - index) % 3 != 0) {
                stop1 = dna.length();    
            }
            int stop2 = dna.indexOf("taa", index);
            if (stop2 == -1 || (stop2 - index) % 3 != 0) {
                stop2 = dna.length();    
            }
            int stop3 = dna.indexOf("tag", index);
            if (stop3 == -1 || (stop3 - index) % 3 != 0) {
                stop3 = dna.length();    
            }
            return Math.min(stop1, Math.min(stop2,stop3));
        }  


        public static void printAll(String dna){
            String dnaLow = dna.toLowerCase();
            int start = 0;
            while (true) {
                int loc = dnaLow.indexOf( "atg", start );

                int stop = findStopIndex( dnaLow, loc+3 );
                if ( stop != dna.length() ) {
                    System.out.println( dna.substring(loc, stop) );
                    start = stop + 3;
                } else {
                    start = start + 3;
                }    
            }
        }

        // demo
        public static void testFinder() {

            String dna1 = "ATGAAATGAAAA";
            System.out.println("DNA string is: \n" +dna1);
            System.out.println("Genes found are:");
            printAll(dna1);
            System.out.print("\n");


        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            testFinder();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "we have to print out everything between a start codon atg and one of three end codons tga, taa, and tag" - it's not clear to me what you want to do, please clarify your requirement. Examples might help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your printAll() function.

```
public static void printAll(String dna){
    String dnaLow = dna.toLowerCase();
    int start = 0;
    while (true) {
        int loc = dnaLow.indexOf( "atg", start );

        int stop = findStopIndex( dnaLow, loc+3 );
        if ( stop != dna.length() ) {
            System.out.println( dna.substring(loc, stop) );
            start = stop + 3;
        } else {
            start = start + 3;
        }    
    }
}
```

The main issue here is you are using too many variables.  You should only need the start variable, not the loc variable.  If we switch all occurrences of loc and get rid of the ugly arithmetic the function will look like this:

```
public static void printAll(String dna){
    String dnaLow = dna.toLowerCase();
    int start = 0;
    while (true) {
        start = dnaLow.indexOf( "atg", start ) + 3;
        int stop = findStopIndex( dnaLow, start );
        if ( stop != dna.length() ) {
            System.out.println( dna.substring(start, stop) );
            start = stop + 3;
        } else {
            start = start + 3;
        } 
    }
}
```

But we are not done.  If we run the code this way, things will work much the same as your code currently does.  Now what the indexOf() function does is return the index of the start of the string. So when you are finding the index of ATG, it returns zero. Well, the string you want starts at index 3 because atg is three characters long. This is easily solved by adding three to the result. You need to do this everytime, not just when your if statement fails. If this is supposed to output multiple genes, you might try restructuring your code a bit, preferably away from an infinite loop.  The main issue being that in your if statement, you are checking if we are at the end of the string and then setting start equal to stop+3.  But then the loop runs again and it gets set to the index of atg again.  This is a symptom of ditching the loc variable admittedly.

```
public static void printAll(String dna) {
    String dnaLow = dna.toLowerCase();
    int start = 0;
    int stop = 0;
    start = dnaLow.indexOf( "atg", start ) + 3;
    while (start < dna.length())
    {
        stop = findStopIndex( dnaLow, start );
        System.out.println( dna.substring(start, stop) );
        start = stop + 3;
    }   
}
```

I also initialized the stop variable outside of the loop, but that is personal preference and it doesn't matter.

Edit:
For loops are your friend when dealing with multiple items.  This is obvious in the findStopIndex() function.  This function is actually easier to write with a for loop.  What we will do is create arrays to hold our codons and indexes so there is one index per codon.  Then we iterate through them trying find a stop index for each.  If we don't find one, then we set the corresponding index to the end of the string.

```
public static int findStopIndex(String dna, int index){
    String endCodons[] = { "tga", "taa", "tag"};
    int stopIndexes[] = new int[3];
    for(int i = 0; i<3 ;i++)  
    {
        stopIndexes[i] = dna.indexOf(endCodons[i], index);
        if(stopIndexes[i]==-1||(stopIndexes[i] - index) % 3 != 0)
            stopIndexes[i] = dna.length();
    }
    return Math.min(stopIndexes[0], Math.min(stopIndexes[1],stopIndexes[2]));
}
```

Comment: I suggest to replace the hard-coded number 3 with `"atg".length` to make this clearer. Better yet, extract "atg" into a variable to make it easier to change.

Comment: It is easier to understand, but I'd be suspect of the performance vs a hard coded number.

Comment: The performance difference should be negligible. Compared to creating the substring, a few variable reads won't matter at all. The `println` is most likely to be the slowest part of this program.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm the kind of person that bit-shifts instead of dividing or multiplying by two even though most modern compilers fix this anyways.  I KNOW it doesn't matter, but I can't help myself.